# Access a single element from list of child elements of a reference in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, reference, nuxt.js

I'm not much familiar with nuxt or vue but I've been learning from the documentation and examples.
I've tried searching through so many articles but I can't find out a simple way to do this

My component is

```
<template>
    <div ref="parent">
        <div v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.id">{{ post.title }}</div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [
                {id: 1, title: 'title 1'},
                {id: 5, title: 'title 2'},
                {id: 7, title: 'title 3'}
            ]
        };
    },
    methods: {
        doSomething(){
            // I have to use the index of div but I want to use post.id
            const div = this.$refs.parent.children[0];
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Now I want to access the child element of my reference div with help of `post.id`
Currently I am accessing the child elements using index.

There are going to be a lot of child elements so I don't want to add a reference to all of them.

The component in example is a child component and I'm accessing its method in a parent component and passing the `post.id` from there as an argument in `doSomething(post.id)` method

Can someone guide me on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can share the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the ID to the method and then use it to retrieve the element that you want to change from the  array declared in data().

```
<template>
    <div ref="parent">
        <div v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.id">
           {{ post.title }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [
                {id: 1, title: 'title 1'},
                {id: 5, title: 'title 2'},
                {id: 7, title: 'title 3'}
            ]
        };
    },
    methods: {
        doSomething(id){
           this.posts.map(x => {
               if(x.id === id){
                  //edit X here, where x is the post
                  console.log(x,'here I am');
               }
            return x
          });
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: But there is not going to be a `@click` event on the child div or any other event

Comment: In my question I used `child` to refer the iterated divs from `ref="parent"` divs perspective

Comment: I was missing a part of your question. I updated my answer, you can pass the id to the function and then use it to modify your array.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not trying to get the `post` instead I want to access the child `div`  (DOM element) of `ref="parent"`.

Comment: What you want to do to the div? Accessing it with  `this.$refs.parent.children[0];` in this simple component seems most probably a misuse of vue functionalities.

Comment: I've simplified the component  as much as I could. In actual component, these are `<video>` elements and I want to access the `<video>` element by using `post.id`

Comment: So give a unique id or ref to the video elements by combining the "post.id" with some string. like `<video :ref="'video_'+video.id" ...>` and then you can directly call them inside a method `this.$refs.video_1.$el`

Comment: I'm aware of that part. There are going to be a lot of `posts` say 100s
is it ok to make so many references? Wont that effect the performance?
If I assign an `id` to video element using `post.id`. Should I use vanilla javascript to access the element in that case?

Comment: Best would be what you need to access on the video element. Depending on that, I would create a component just for holding videos, call it my-video, then inside this you can set all the methods you need, like play() etc etc. In this way you will be able to access all the properties and functions you need in a pure vue style. 

Using id with a clean vanilla-js is not a good idea, cause vue works with a virtual dom that renders the actual dom, and this goes  just in one way. Same as props.

Comment: Thats exactly how I've made it. A separate component with all my video elements. And I'm aware of virtual DOM part thats why I'm not working with IDs. But to play/pause a video we need to access the video element directly, to call HTML5 Video API methods. Thats why I need to access a specific video element from list. Dont want to add references as there will be a lot of videos. So we come back to point zero... How to select a specific element with `post.id` from a list.